# Roots of $z^4 - 3z^2 + 1 = 0$.

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

> Show that the solutions of $z^4 - 3z^2 + 1 = 0$ are given by $$z = 2\cos 36^{\def\o{\mathrm{o}}\o}, 2\cos 72^\o, 2\cos 216^\o, 2\cos 252^\o.$$ Hence show that
>
> - $\cos 36^\o = \frac 14(\sqrt{5}+1)$
> - $\cos 72^\o = \frac 14(\sqrt{5}-1)$

I can solve for the roots, however I could not express them as the question wanted. Is there a specific way to express the root in kinda polar form without the imaginary part.

Comment: I think these numbers refer to the real part of the root $z$. If a real part is
$$
Re(z) = 2\cos{36^{\circ}} \qquad \Rightarrow \qquad Im(z) = 2\sin{36^{\circ}} 
$$

Comment: The question clearly states that all roots are real. Why would you need a polar form ?

Comment: Is your problem about showing $z=2\cos 36^\circ$ etc are roots of the quartic, or about expressing roots of the quartic as $\pm(1\pm\sqrt5)/4$ (independent $\pm$s)?

Comment: Do you need to solve the equation? Maybe you can set $s = z^2$ .

Answer (score 1):

I would solve the equation $$z^4-3z^2+1=0$$ by substituting $$z^2=t$$ we get
$$t^2-3t+1=0$$ and by the quadratic formula we obtain the solutions as
$$t_{1,2}=\frac{3}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{9}{4}-1}$$
Can you finish?

Comment: But how do you get the trigonometric expressions for the roots?

Comment: see here https://www.math-only-math.com/exact-value-of-cos-36-degree.html

Answer (score 1):

Let $w=e^{i\theta}$. Try to search for $z=w+\bar w=w+\frac{1}{w}$. Setting it in the equation gives
$$
w^8+w^6+w^4+w^2+1=\frac{w^{10}-1}{w^2-1}=0.
$$
Now you need to pick those $w$ that make $w^{10}=1$ and $w^2\ne 1$.

Comment: Thanks for the guide, i nvr thought of using conjugate to get 2Re(w) and use it for z. It is brilliant.

Comment: I agree, it is brilliant (+1)